# Bootstrap - why text starts an inch left from browser window left edge?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

Here is my simplified HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" >
          <p><h4>Top Left</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" >
          <p><h4>Top Right</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" >
          <p><h4>Bottom Left</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" >
          <p><h4>Bottom Right</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I expect to see in browser:

```
Home     Search      Log out

Top Left           Top Right

Bottom Left        Bottom Right
```

Here is what I see in both Firefox and Chrome:

```
Home     Search      Log out

p Left           
p Right

tom Left        
tom Right
```

Why?

Comment: lol how did you get the `tom` in your code though?

Comment: please recreate this issue in a fiddle.

Comment: I've updated your answer to include a stack snippet.  If that's too significant a change or if it doesn't really demonstrate your issue, feel free to edit it again or revert it back.

Comment: This could be the columns stacking too early.  Have you tried using `col-sm-x` or `col-xs-x` instead of your `col-md-x`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are defining sizes for medium sized screen and testing it on small or extra small screen. You need to explicitly specify sizes for them. Add `col-sm-*` for small screens and `col-xs-*` for extra small screens.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-md-12">
        <li class=" col-md-4 col-xs-4 "><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
        <li class=" col-md-4 col-xs-4 "><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
        <li class="  col-md-4 col-xs-4"><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
          <p><h4>Top Left</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
          <p><h4>Top Right</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
          <p><h4>Bottom Left</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
          <p><h4>Bottom Right</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now, I am testing it on a normal laptop screen, I believe 1600x1200

Comment: Are you seeing the same output as before?

Comment: Try running my code in full screen. It is working exactly as you would like it to.